# Which HID key code to use for KEYCODE_BACK button mapping?

Tags: python-3.x, hid, android-9.0-pie, raspberry-pi-zero

Platform:

- STB Xiaomi Mi Box S 4

OS Version:

- Android Version 9

Issue description:

- I want to use the USB keyboard gadget to control the box. I mapped the remote controller buttons (arrow buttons/select/home) into corresponding HID key codes following the [page](https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices#properties). However, none of the specified/corresponding key codes (0x00f1, 0x009e) for the KEYCODE_BACK button is working as expected.

Question:

- Do you maybe know which HID key code should be used for the BACK button?

Appreciated any help!

Comment: My understanding of the documentation that you linked to is that the ESCAPE key HID usage (0x00070029) may be redispatched as the Android KEYCODE_BACK key if KEYCODE_ESCAPE is not handled by the android app. That may be worth testing. Alternatively, you could try adding the Consumer Page "AC Back" HID usage (0x000C0224) to your HID report descriptor and Android should see it as the KEYCODE_BACK key. BTW, the USB HID Usage Tables specification reserves keyboard usages 0x000700E8 to 0x0007FFFF so I think Android should not be assigning arbitrary functions to them (as shown in their table).

Answer (score 0):

I found detailed document about HID usages. I hope you can find your answer from the pdf.

---

PDF: https://usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_21.pdf

Comment: Thanks Árpád Csepi! Unfortunately this not resolves the issue as none of corresponding keycodes work correctly.

Comment: Please put the answer into the answer. Just a link is a bad answer, since it won't provide any information once that link goes offline. Also, you need to press a link and search a whole 318 page PDF for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code to determine if the Key is Back / Menu on the Android device / key code

```
if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK  || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_MODE) && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        if( onBackPressed() ) { // function to determine if we should block the action in your code and do something else return true if you want to proc
            return true;
        } else {
            // let the Android system handle the back button
            return false;
        }
    }
```